# Turning Off Specific Click Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/w55usyqk/

When you click the div there are two separate click events fired. They print out "click" and "clicked" respectively in the console log.

```
$("div").on("click", function() { console.log("click"); });
$("div").on("click", function() { console.log("clicked"); });
```

If you tap on the button it will remove both event declarations from the div object

```
$("button").on("click", function() { $("div").off("click"); });
```

However, what if I just needed to remove a single click event? Is this stored in some sort of event array where I could do something along the lines of `$("div").off("click")[1]`; or is it impossible to turn off one without turning off the other as well?

I did try looking for the answer if it's been posted before. I think this is one of those questions that's hard to word, so though there may be an answer out there, it's difficult to pin down.

Comment: You can use `this` to get the clicked `div` and turn that handler off. `$(this).off("click")`

Comment: @tymeJV Thanks for responding. $(this).off("click"); will still remove all click events from the object. I would like to remove just one of the click events.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use namespaces to easily do this. When you create your event handlers, add the namespace after the event. Ex:

```
$("div").on("click.namespace1", function() { console.log("click"); });
$("div").on("click.namespace2", function() { console.log("clicked"); });
```

then for your button, use the namespace of the event to remove:

```
// remove only the event for namespace2
$("button").on("click", function() { $("div").off(".namespace2"); });
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Lqugv5j7/)**

Some more on [namespaces for events](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> An event name can be qualified by event namespaces that simplify
>   removing or triggering the event. For example, `"click.myPlugin.simple"`
>   defines both the myPlugin and simple namespaces for this particular
>   click event. A click event handler attached via that string could be
>   removed with `.off("click.myPlugin")` or `.off("click.simple")` without
>   disturbing other click handlers attached to the elements. Namespaces
>   are similar to CSS classes in that they are not hierarchical; only one
>   name needs to match. Namespaces beginning with an underscore are
>   reserved for jQuery's use.

Comment: Excellent! This works perfectly as well. I've never heard of using event namespaces before. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: This is awesome. I had no idea this was possible. @j08691 thanks for sharing!

Comment: Although the other answer worked correctly, I chose to accept this answer per meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13396/… which states to choose the answer that you actually used. I chose using namespaces because I think it adds less clutter to the code. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 4):

Use named functions as event handlers, so you can then reference what handler you want to unbind:

```
function clicOne() {console.log("click");};
function clicTwo() {console.log("clicked");};

$("div").on("click", clickOne);
$("div").on("click", clicTwo);

$("button").on("click", function() { $("div").off("click", clickOne); });
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfect. I really appreciate it! For others who may find this question helpful, I plugged it into the original fiddle so that it's easier to see. http://jsfiddle.net/w55usyqk/1/

Comment: Although your answer worked correctly, I chose to accept the other answer per http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13396/which-answer-do-i-accept-if-i-have-multiple-correct-answers which states to choose the answer that you actually used. I chose the other answer in using namespaces because I think it adds less clutter to the code. No hard feelings and I appreciate your help!