# Removing Javascript Events

Tags: javascript, events

So I have a element that has an existing Click Event Handler and I am trying to

- Add **second** Click Event Handler(Item.executeSelectClick) that will prevent the **first** Click Handler
- Then if the user Clicks Proceed $('#out-of-policy').find('#c-modal-proceed').click
- Remove my second Click Event Handler(Item.executeSelectClick) and proceed with the original Event Handler.

  - button.removeEventListener('click', Item.executeSelectClick);
  - setTimeout(function(){$(button).click()}, 3000);

Please note I don't have a reference first Click Handler and I will not be able to get one.

```
Item.executeSelectClick = function(event){
    var button = event.target;

    $('#out-of-policy').find('#c-modal-proceed').click(function(){
        $('#out-of-policy').css('display', 'none');
        button.removeEventListener('click', Item.executeSelectClick);
        setTimeout(function(){$(button).click()}, 3000);
    });

    $('#out-of-policy').show();

    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return false;
}
```

Currently what is happening is the **second** Event Handler is not being remove and when I click the button setTimeout(function(){$(button).click()}, 3000); the **second** Click Event Handler continues to intercept the request.

Comment: Can I ask what the overall goal is here? This seems like a very weird interaction between the page and code.

Comment: I think this is actually a duplicate of a question I had asked before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33045624/turning-off-specific-click-event

Comment: @ManBearPixel the overall goal is to intercept an event I have no control of and introduce a required user input to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on top of a [previous SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33045624/turning-off-specific-click-event) that discussed namespaces in JavaScript event setup and assuming you are using jQuery (as seen in your question) this code snippet should be useful for your situation. The first click on `.target` will stop default event propagations, run your code, and then remove the click event handler that was setup:

```
$('.target').on('click.stopDefault', function(event){ 
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();  

  console.log('Your code executed here...');

  $('.target').off('click.stopDefault');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a clone to do your stuff and leave the original button, as you didn't want to tamper with it anyways, hiding it until needed.

```js
$(function() {
  var $original = $('#original');
  var $dupe = $original.clone(false);
  
  // just something that'll hold a response
  var $response = $('#response').find('span');
  
  // position the clone with the original
  $original.after($dupe);
  // hide the original button
  $original.hide();
  
  // assign the clone something to do
  $dupe.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // clone stuff here
    $response.text('attack of the clone!');
    // when clone finished doing its thing, 
    // simply hide it and show the original button
    $dupe.hide();
    $original.show();
  });
  
  // nothing here, say the original got clicked...
  $original.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $response.text('original clicked!');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="original" href="#">click me</a>
<p id="response">response: <span></span>
</p>
```